# How to move files from %temp% to shell:startup

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Issue:
Can't move files to the selected location.

Comment: 
Using Bat_to_Exe_converter - to extract files in the temporary directory, from which the files should be moved to the shell:startup directory.

Using the application (Bat_to_Exe Converter) hasn't been an issue before to move files to the given directory, when trying to move the folder - it says: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Code:

```
ping localhost -n 2 >nul   //This is so the files have time to extract in the %temp% directory.
move "%TEMP%\TheGoose\" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"  //This is where the file paths are specified from which the files need to be moved.
pause
```

Comment: You don't! Unless they're all shortcuts, (`.lnk` files), _as that's all you should be putting in Startup_.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) from the source directory.

```
move "%TEMP%\TheGoose" "%APPDATA%\Micro...
```

Or, if you do not want `TheGoose` moved, specify a wildcard. The following means all files in the `TheGoose` directory.

```
move "%TEMP%\TheGoose\*" "%APPDATA%\Micro...
```

Comment: I didn't understand what i was doing wrong, i tried your version, still didn't seem to work, i had to take a harder route, today i finished the application, although i'm unable to fully test it, for computers that use C:\\ This project will work, for other, i'l have to test it more, if you'd like, you can test it here, just please don't re-post it. https://mega.nz/#F!KzARCQoS!2i0EwnBrnH-zEtiJ585JoA

Comment: Note* Only The "RunGoose- Finished.exe" Will work properly, because it was made to only work when everything is compiled into an exe. The exe has all the files it needs and has the commands to finish what it was made to do.

Comment: This application was made to move some files to the startup directory, if you are familiar with the Desktop Goose meme thingy, this is kinda like an installer, i know there were easier ways to do this, but i tried making a batch version.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what i was doing wrong, had to take a harder route, finished the project today, the files/code can be viewed/tested in the link bellow, just please don't re-upload. https://mega.nz/#F!KzARCQoS!2i0EwnBrnH-zEtiJ585JoA